# How to respond to a mouse click

Tags: tcl, mouse

I am trying to obtain some text from a local website using `wget.exe`.
I use TCL code (shown below) to launch `wget.exe`. While TCL waits for a response and result from `wget.exe`, there is no response to the mouse. Not even to the little x in the top right hand corner of the window to shut down the program.

I have searched the internet for some answers and only find results pointing to bindings.

```
while {[catch {set line1 [exec wget.exe \
        --no-check-certificate \
        -q \
        -O - \
        -T $tout \
        -t 1 \
        $serverip$url]}]} {

    # ACCESS HAS FAILED AND TEST HOW MANY TIMES?
       Some more code here
}
```

While waiting for an output from `wget.exe` I would like to be able to abort and shut down the program with a mouse click before `wget.exe` times out.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're doing this in the context of a Tk GUI…

What you need to do is to run the subprocess asynchronously so that the GUI event loop continues to be serviced while the subprocess is running. This is substantially easier to do in your case if we use Tcl 8.6 (or later) as we can use a coroutine to simply everything a lot.

```
# A global variable that you can hook into the GUI to get a crash stop
set StopRightNow 0

coroutine doWget apply {{} {
    global tout serverip url StopRightNow
    while true {
        set subprocess [open |[list wget.exe \
            --no-check-certificate \
            -q \
            -O - \
            -T $tout \
            -t 1 \
            $serverip$url]]
        fconfigure $subprocess -blocking 0
        # Arrange for the coroutine to resume whenever there's something to do
        fileevent $subprocess readable [info coroutine]
        set lines {}
        while {![eof $subprocess]} {
            yield
            # Check for override!
            if {$StopRightNow} return
            if {[gets $subprocess line] >= 0} {
                lappend lines $line
            }
        }
        fconfigure $subprocess -blocking 1
        if {![catch {close $subprocess} errors]} {
            break
        }
        # Do something to handle the errors here...
        puts "Problem when reading; will retry\n$errors"
    }
    # At this point, $lines has the list of lines read from the wget subprocess. For example:
    puts "Read the output..."
    foreach line $lines {
        puts "[incr lineNumber]: $line"
    }
}}
```

OK, that's a bit of a big chunk. Let's break out the core of that into a procedure.

```
proc asyncRunSubprocess args {
    global StopRightNow
    set subprocess [open |$args]
    fconfigure $subprocess -blocking 0
    # Arrange for the coroutine to resume whenever there's something to do
    fileevent $subprocess readable [info coroutine]
    # Accumulate the subprocess's stdout
    set lines {}
    while {![eof $subprocess]} {
        yield
        if {$StopRightNow} {
            return {{} -1 interrupted {}}
        }
        if {[gets $subprocess line] >= 0} {
            lappend lines $line
        }
    }
    # Close down the subprocess; we've got an EOF
    fconfigure $subprocess -blocking 1
    set code [catch {close $subprocess} errors opts]
    return [list $lines $code $errors $opts]
}
```

Then we can make the outer coroutine like this:

```
coroutine doWget apply {{} {
    global tout serverip url
    while true {
        set results [asyncRunSubprocess \
                wget.exe --no-check-certificate -q -O - -T $tout -t 1 $serverip$url]
        lassign $results lines code errors
        if {$code < 0} return elseif {$code == 0} break
        # Do something to handle the errors here...
        puts "Problem when reading; will retry\n$errors"
    }
    # At this point, $lines has the list of lines read from the wget subprocess. For example:
    puts "Read the output..."
    foreach line $lines {
        puts "[incr lineNumber]: $line"
    }
}}
```

Note that Tcl's coroutines (unlike with many other languages) can quite happily suspend within procedures that they call.

Comment: It's possible to do this without a coroutine, and has been for as long as I've been using Tcl and Tk, but the code is a mess of procedures calling each other in continuation passing style and is _quite_ horrible to understand.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer. Unfortunately I don't use 8.6. I have downloaded 8.5 and 8.6 but they are not loaded by vtcl. V8.4 works fine. I should have indicated that I use 8.4. With 8.6 I would not be able to create the TK windows easily. I will however, study the 'coroutine, yeald etc' and the method you used. At this stage I don't yet follow the whole process.

Comment: Donal, you mention that it is possible to this without croutine. It would be interesting to see those procedures. Do you have a link to the procedures you used?